# Import seems to fail with TexStudio after reinstallation. Why?

Tags: errors, texstudio, highlighting, import, syntax-highlighting

I reinstalled Texsudio on a new SSD yesterday. After that I only encounter problems, Nothing changed to my actual MikTex installation, which has always been on my boot disk.

E.g. when I import my preamble located in a different directory, texstudio tells me the "file is not found" despite compiling withouth showing any error messages

[image: In the structur, I am told the file is not found although the path is scorrect and TexStudio utilizes the commands provided in the preamble.tex file]

The syntax highlighting is also all over the place in the Preamble. Can someone please help me fix the problem?

Kind regards!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is the file `PreambleEN.tex` still on drive `C:` in directory `Users/Manuel/OneDrive.../Master`? The sample document compiles without errors, because it doesn't use any of the definitions from `PreambleEN.tex`.

Comment: Yes it is, but it actually uses the commands defined in the preamble. It is so weird

Comment: If you want to clarify the situation, post the relevant part of the log file (error message together with some lines before it). Moreover, create a copy of the document and minimize it, but retaining the error message.

Comment: That‘s the weird thing. The error is not reproducible. It seems to be down to my TexStudio installation. 
I checked it on my laptop and everything's fine, as it was before reinstalling TexStudio on my new SSD. There are no error messages either. The syntax highlighting is a pure mess in the 'PreambleEN.tex' file & occasionally, the program tells me the file is not found in the directory, although the stated directory is clearly correct.